# Debugging from VSC installed in Windows 10 pointed to Ubuntu (in windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I have Visual Studio Code installed in Windows 10. I would like to set it to run python that is in Ubuntu which is installed in Windows 10. I need to debugging code with the same setting with VSC.

Is there possibility to do it as this way?

Comment: Do you mean you want to debug something running in WSL?

Comment: @gdc Yes. I would like to debug  something in WLS. Do you have some ideias to do as soon?